# how to divide videoCapture in 2 theads to process video faster in opencv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, python-multithreading

I'm trying to start 2 process to read the same video in opencv, each process will read the video and set the start start frame .

example:

- `process 1 -> read video and read the file 0-4000`
- `process 2 -> read the same video(again) and set the frame to 4000-8000`

My problem is when the second process sets the video frame to 4xxx, process 1 finishes your work, it seems both processes are using the same videoCapture instance.

My simplified code is this, you can copy and past it in your machine that it will run:

```py
    import cv2
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    # Process frame is a method that will be executed in each processor
    def processFrames(params):
        # All params is correct, including the startAt and endAt 
        processId, startAt, endAt, url= params

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

        #[PROBLEM IS HERE]
        # The problem is here, when I set the first video crop for 1-4xxx 
        # frames, it brokes, but the second processors that crop the video 
        # by (4xxx-8xxx) works well
        cap.set(startAt,endAt-1) #If I remove this line, everything works

        # Printing what processor is working in frames
        while(cap.isOpened()):
            print(processId)

            done, img = cap.read()
            if not done:
                #The processor 1 ends when the processor 2 set the frames to >4000
                print('done')
                break


        cap.release()


    url = './video.mkv'
    #Getting the total frames in a video
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    total = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    cap.release()

    #Define what frame the process will use
    startAt = 1
    halfMovie = total//2

    #each process will have an ID
    id1 = 0
    id2 = 1

    #processes params
    params = []
    params.append((id1, startAt, halfMovie, url))
    params.append((id2, halfMovie+1, total, url))

    #lauching processes
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map_async(processFrames, params)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Because I'm printing the processor's ID (0 or 1) for each frame, when I run this code I must to got a result like this:

```sh
0
0
1
0
1
0
1
1
0
```

But I'm getting this result:

```
0 #the processor 0 starts
1 # the processor 1 starts
1
1
1
1
done  # the processor 0 finish your job because don't have more frames to read (I guess)
1
1
1
1
1
... # Only processor 1 works
```

I already try to use the `pool.map`, `pool.map_async`, `pool.apply_async`, `Thread.start`, `Thread objects` but all implementations got the same result